# Where can I find sample application files to deploy on JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: azure, jboss

I started to work on JBoss. In Azure, I am trying to deploy files. I tried deploying .war file for Tomcat server. I found the tomcat .war file sample application download. Similarly, where can I download sample applications for JBoss EAP 7?

I tried searching different websites. It didn't work. Please help me with the sample application files for JBOSS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if This link is helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/migration/migrate-jboss-eap-to-jboss-eap-on-azure-app-service

Answer (score 1):

JBoss EAP provides Quickstarts as a separate download or via git https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts